# "The stylesheet was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html" is not "text/css"

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, stylesheet

I have a javascript application and when I run it on firefox I am getting the following erro on the console:

> "The stylesheet was not loaded because
>   its MIME type, "text/html" is not
>   "text/css".

DumbStuck!!

EDIT:
Note that it tells that "The stylesheet ABCD..."
But ABCD is actually an HTML file.

Edit (**ANSWER**) : Actually I had wrongly put `href=""`, and hence the html file was refenecing itself as the CSS. Mozilla had the similar bug [once](http://www.mozdev.org/pipermail/project_owners/2008-January/010830.html), and it is from there I got the answer. But everyone's else answers helped me too. Thanks.

Comment: Can you supply some example markup?

Comment: I guess you include `ABCD` the wrong way...

Comment: Accepting this is closed, and old - however, if it helps someone else. I've just had the exact same error message in console, but discovered the url was broken. The error message was not identifying the actual issue. (For clarity, my css file had the correct type attribute and suffix: .css, not .html as indicated in some of these answers).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually I had wrongly put href="", and hence the html file was referencing itself as the CSS. Mozilla had the similar bug [once](http://www.mozdev.org/pipermail/project_owners/2008-January/010830.html), and I got the answer from there.

Answer (score 27):

In the head section of your html document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/ABCD.css">
```

Your css file should be css only and not contain any markup.

Comment: The OP said, `ABCD` **is** an HTML file. So it is wrongly recognized as CSS (I guess).

Comment: Did not worked for me

Answer (score 10):

This is more likely an issue at your server side. you request style sheet page "Styles/Site.css" from the server of type "text/css", but your server might be responding to this request with "test/html". I had this issue when my server was running in python and it was replying to requested css files with header text/html (as that of my index.html file). I re-arranged my server code and assigned the correct headers to its corresponding pages and my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use it as a CSS file, probably by using

```
<link rel=stylesheet href=ABCD.html>
```

or

```
<style>
@import url("ABCD.html");
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what did it for me in .htaccess (it could be that you had a directive making all files load as MIME type text/html):

In .htaccess

```
AddType text/css .css
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu In the conf file: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/your-file.conf

change

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js .xml .htc .css
```

to:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js .xml .htc
```

Answer (score 0):

Review any .htaccess. Maybe, a .htaccess rule is interfering with the right output. Try browsing your CSS resource directly in your address bar, it must be presented in text format.