# How to solve error for stylesheet file It shows It was not loaded because its MIME type.? 

Tags: asp.net, css, stylesheet, mime-types

I getting error in loading .css file in my asp.net Web Application, I got error message like

```
Error: The stylesheet http://'<Website URL>'/css/default.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
```

How can I solved it.?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190459/the-stylesheet-was-not-loaded-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-text-cs

Comment: What are you, a "Chav" .. Please fix your title.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't solve it contact your web host, their server is kicking out the wrong mime type for the file extension

Comment: @Beliskner Is any way to debug it and get solution for it.

Comment: Please post the HTML you are using to reference your stylesheet. If possible please post a link to the stylesheet in question too.