# Styles not working after gulp watch task because of mime-type text/html

Tags: html, css, gulp

I have a `gulp` `watch` `task`, which compiles and concats all `scss` files to one `css` file. In my index I `link` the `css` file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css">
```

This is my `gulp` `watch` `task`:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function () {
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});
```

And this is my `gulp` file with the `sass` task:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss in app/scss
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
});
```

After I start the `gulp` `watch` task, my browser opens my site but the style is wrong. I got this error: `Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/css/styles.css/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Here's the whole gulpfile.js:

```
//My Gulpfile
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var dev = require('gulp-dev');


gulp.task('sass', function () {
return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss in 
app/scss
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function () {
gulp.watch('app/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: 'app'
    },
   })
 });

 gulp.task('dev', function() {
  gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(dev(true))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('index.html'));
 });
```

I don't know why this happens, I'm using the `type="text/css"` attribute in my `link` like described in this solution: ["The stylesheet was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html" is not "text/css"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190459/the-stylesheet-was-not-loaded-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-text-c)

After starting the `gulp` `watch` task I have to make a change in one of my `scss` files and than the whole style is correct? Any ideas what I'm doint wrong?

Comment: do file http://localhost:3000/css/styles.css exists  - when you go to that link in separate tab - ?

Comment: It says `Cannot GET  /css/styles.css`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./app/css/styles.css">
```

I change `href="./css/styles.css"` to `href="./app/css/styles.css"`. You can also change `type="text/css"` to `type="text/html"` - however this solution in low satisfyable

**UPDATE**
In your gulp-file you have line

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/css/'))
```

This mean that processed files are stored in `./app/css` directory, so probably your webserwer dont see it (maybe this files must by stored do different directory like `./public/css` - it depends of your project.

Comment: It didn't work..

Comment: does file localhost:3000/app/css/styles.css exists (check in separate browser tab)? If exist then you can also try this: href="app/css/styles.css" (I remove `./` at beginning, you can also try to remove only dot `.`)

Comment: Also didn't work..

Comment: @danijel.m update your question and provide your full gulp file

Comment: I've updated it, hope it helps you.

Comment: @danijel.m does file localhost:3000/app/css/styles.css exists? (check in separate browser tab)

Comment: @danijel.m I update my answer