# React "text/html" is not a valid JavaScript MIME type

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I'm trying to add external javascript to my React project.I have a Footer.js component where I add my javascript files. I'm using the `react-helmet` library.

```
class Footer extends Component {

    render () {
        return (
        <div>
            <Helmet>
                <script src="../../assets/scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript" />

                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/metismenu"></script>
            </Helmet>
        </div> 
        );
    }
}
```

It is returning a warning in the browser:

```
The script from “http://localhost:3000/assets/scripts/main.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

It is clearly a JavaScript file, why is it saying that the type is "text/html"?

Thanks

Comment: Probably a server issue,  see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190459/the-stylesheet-was-not-loaded-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-text-c

Comment: I'm running it localhost

Comment: Apache, python script, nginx... windows or linux ?

Comment: It is a react project. I tag as react and put it in the title ;-)

Comment: Ok, but if your server is on linux and you create the file with windows, maybe it's a file header issue -> use dos2unix. If you use apache to render your file, check your configuration to see if js files are served as text/javascript in mime types configuration.

Comment: I'm in localhost environment. I use Mac

Comment: So you are running an index.html, all externals scripts loads but main.js ? How do you run the server ?

Comment: @JB_DELR I'm sorry, do you know how React project works/run? You create a project using npm. Then, you run it with npm start

Comment: I run it with webpack and encore with yarn on apache dev server.

Comment: Now I know how do you run the server, I can tell you to have a look here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/658