# Why styles.css file doesn't apply to the page

Tags: html, css, frontend, ejs

[image]

I'm moved styles.css file to every location in my project and tried to link it in html file. I moved it even in the same folder where html files are, href autocompletion works(line 9 on image), seems styles.css is visible from html file but still it's doesn't applied to the page. Can't find out the reason...

Comment: You need to add the `type` attribute with the proper value when linking styling sheets.

Comment: It doesn't help, besides according to documentation: if rel="stylesheet", the browser will assume the type is "text/css" https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_type.asp

Comment: It is still better to include it and you need a `./` in front of the `style.css`

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">  Steel doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't upload code, results or data as images for these reasons: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was in express.js code. I didn't use spatial middleware for static files:
**app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));**
here is  the documentation page:https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

After adding this in server code, in html href should be the rest of path to css file, in my case:

Answer (score 0):

As far as your syntax for the style link, it's fine. You could get into a browser console (typically hit F12), then browse the page watching the network tab to make sure the browser finds the css file and loads it.

But I think your problem may be elsewhere. On the code you show, your entire nav (navigation) section is inside the head section of the page (i.e. before /head appears). That's not where it belongs. It should be inside the body section section further down. That's certainly a problem and may be what you think is a css issue.

- sorry about the edit. I didn't know html tags would be eliminated

Edit: As regards the html MIME type instead of the correct CSS MIME type, you might look at this link and check your server configuration and/or .htaccess file to make sure the server hasn't been told to parse css as if it was html: ["The stylesheet was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html" is not "text/css"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190459/the-stylesheet-was-not-loaded-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-text-c)

Also please show the CSS file, to confirm it actually is css and not actually html.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adding nav section inside body instead of header doesn't help. Also I have an error in network, browser cant find css file. It was searching in localhost:3000/styles.css. I changed css path in html, set it starting from root <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/public/css/styles.css"> but again I'm receiving same error in browser network: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/src/public/css/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: 3 solutions for this type of error from here https://exerror.com/mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-stylesheet-mime-type-and-strict-mime-checking-is-enabled/ also doesn't help

Comment: css file contains only css:    .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}
.navbar {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.navbar-nav  li a:hover {
    color: #1abc9c;
}

.footer-padding {
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.footer {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.footer p {
 margin-top: 25px;
 font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
}